# Cocos2D replaceScene doesn't load image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am working with Cocos2D v1.0.1 and I have a bug with this code

```
CCScene *scene = [TDGameHandler scene:kGameSolo andViewController:self];
if(![[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene])
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene]; // RUN THE SCENE

} else {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
}
```

The first time there is no problem, but the second time there is no image load.
I tried to pop and push the scene but it didn't work either, I also tried to add startAnimation but the application crash.

[image]

I just tried to end the CCScene with this code :

```
[[CCDirectorIOS sharedDirector] end];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
```

But it crash.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So how do you create the image in your scene, and how do you create the scene? Post that code.

Comment: I add in my answer how I initialise the scene, and I have a lot of image in the game added in various way. Even after the game is launch, no image can be load.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:


[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [TDGameHandler scene]];
```